# What are the advantages of using Node.js vs PHP

Tags: php, node.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why and When to use node js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617683/why-and-when-to-use-node-js)

Can someone tell me why all this fuss about node.js ? Is a regular web site (lets say a blog) written in node.js faster compared to same written in some php framework? I know that a web server written in node.js will be faster than apache but how about a real web application that doesn't create threads or something like that?

Comment: why are you comparing client side script with server side script???

Comment: @Rahul: Node.js is server-side Javascript: http://nodejs.org/

Comment: @Rahul Node.js is server-side JavaScript.

Comment: @Rahul — JavaScript is "a programming language" not "an exclusively client side programming language". Node.js is not designed to run inside web browsers.

Comment: @rahul node.js is server side framework!

Comment: @Rahul Node.js isn't designed to run in the browser.  It isn't just straight js.

Comment: @RahulChordiya Ditto what everyone said. Haha.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**Edited:**

There are 2 main advantages:

1. Speed! (Performance)
2. Node.js is event-driven and non-blocking and very good at [handling concurrent requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200821/grasping-the-node-js-alternative-to-multithreading).

Here is a [link](http://zgadzaj.com/benchmarking-node-js-testing-performance-against-apache-php/) to a benchmarking test for node.js against PHP on Apache.

Comment: yes i know that node.js web server is faster than apache :) so it is only the web server advantage?

Comment: Yes, that advantage is too cool to resist but I must also mention there's no large community support yet. So you'd have to be very daring to go with node.JS for your next project.

Comment: I'd say the main advantage is memory usage. If you do long-polling stuff node.js shines since it doesn't require a 100 MB Apache + PHP instance to handle each request. So if you do anything where you have many connections open at the same time - for long periods of time - go with node.js. Usually they coexist well. use node.js for updating a chat panel or similar, not to render your pages.

Comment: You forgot to mention one of the most important features: it's non-blocking!

Comment: A port of WordPress to Node.js would be awesome. hah

Comment: @trusktr http://tryghost.org/

Comment: @NicoBurns That looks freackin' awesome.

Comment: If I make a new freelance site for someone, I'll have to try Ghost.

Comment: last time i checked node.js can't use multi core servers.. :-) so why is that good... since php/apache can use a multi core and it's performance will be better.. :-)

Comment: @Bogdan Check again- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387724/node-js-on-multi-core-machines

Comment: my bad :-) seems that i'm not good with news

Comment: NodeJS is slower then PHP 5.5.5 + React + phpQuery see http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/11/benchmarking-codswallop-nodejs-v-php

Comment: As SeniorDev eluded to, PHP can support non-blocking if you want such a thing. http://reactphp.org/ . I wouldn't say NodeJS is necessarily slower though. As Phil has pointed out in updates, increasing the max connections of NodeJS gets the two setups in his test neck and neck.

Comment: @RobinMaben From my perpective memory leaks would be the biggest disadvantage with Node. Running a web app on a V8 core for days; no wonder.

Comment: How does node JS compare to Php on Apache/nginx when it comes to I/O operation like downloading or streaming large video files from object storage sever like S3 buckets ?

Comment: Normally, you write code in in Java,php,python,c# in "blocking" traditional way, that means when a tasking is executing, other tasks must wait for it to completed (in a queue)

In Nodejs, the basic concept is the "non-blocking" way, that means when a tasking is executing, other tasks dont need to wait for it to completed.

Comment: What about running php on Nginx ?

Comment: how about php7?

Comment: What about in >= 2020 , PHP version 7+ uses less memory and became super fast and secured ?