# traditional web server with node.js

Tags: ajax, node.js, webserver

[Everyone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062614/how-to-decide-when-to-use-nodejs) says node is very good for real time apps, Can I know how good node will be for a [traditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967795/node-js-for-traditional-sites) (hit and serve) web server implementation, say for e.g.

- We don't need to have client(browser) server connectivity all the time.
- We may have 10,000 +  concurrent users.
- We may talk to other services to fetch some part of data.
- We may have some DB to read.

Comment: Node can do all of those things, but so can many other frameworks and languages.

Comment: but can node do it efficiently? or we have a better option ?

Comment: Yes, and so can many other frameworks and languages. It depends entirely on what you're making and what you have experience with.

Comment: @Blender: i have guys knowing both Java and JS, and the above mentioned is my requirement, what will be the best ?

Comment: Take your pick. There's no definitive "best framework" or "best language".