# New web application technology

Tags: web-services, rest, javascript-framework

We're about to start a new project and I've been looking at some of the new web technologies. We want to build a RESTful api which a client can access. To date we've been using python with django/flask to build the api and using jquery for the front end.

I've read quite a bit on javascript frameworks such as emberjs and angular, as well as nodejs solutions like express, meteor and derby. I really like the idea that a site should 'auto update' when the model changes.I'm aware that there are some libraries like gevent which can help facilitate socket level communication, but it seems to be more of a patch than an elegant solution.

Ideally, I don't want to give up a proven technology, ie writing server code in python (or php,ruby whatever) for building my whole app on nodejs. Having a RESTful API is important since we want our services to be open and accessible.

Would it be a bad idea to have 2 servers and 1 client? 1 traditional api server communicating with a javascript framework on the client. Then also run a nodejs server alongside the api server which can somehow talk to the api and if it finds updates, passes it along to the client.

Answer (score 1):

> We want to build a RESTful api which a client can access.
>
> Ideally, I don't want to give up a proven technology, ie writing server code in python (or php,ruby whatever) for building my whole app on nodejs.

Then you should probably go with Rails and Ember.js. I'll quote eviltrout (co-founder of [discourse](http://discourse.org/)) which is build on ember and rails:

> One amazing side effect of a rich client side app is you end up with a battle tested API. Our app has consumed our own API since day one, so we know it works.
>
> If we want to create a native client for Android or iOS, it would be a lot easier because we already speak JSON fluently. If people want to build services that use Discourse, they won’t have to result to screen scraping. It’s a huge win for us and the developers that use our platform. [1](http://eviltrout.com/2013/02/10/why-discourse-uses-emberjs.html)

**However you should keep in mind that ember is as of to date** still a very young framework (rc3 v1.0.0).

I don't know what sort of application you are building (in respect to why you would want to use node) [How to decide when to use Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062614/how-to-decide-when-to-use-nodejs)