# Node.js- A Django-esque Admin interface?

Tags: node.js, django-admin

I'm seriously considering moving from Python to Node.js- the holy grail is within reach....but I do still love Django's Admin interface. Is anyone aware of a new framework that attempts to bring to Node.js what Django did for Python?

Answer (score 2):

Django, as you probably already know, was meant to provide developers with a [fully-featured web framework](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter01.html), capable of "building apps fast and with less code". To achieve that, Django makes a lot of assumptions for you; it decides what ORM to use, what templating engine to use, etc.

Node, on the other hand, is not a web framework, but a platform. It is so thin that you have more freedom deciding how to do things. The idea here is that there is not a single way of [doing things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062614/how-to-decide-when-to-use-nodejs).

Now, to answer your question, [express](http://expressjs.com/) is one of many frameworks that try to bring Node to a higher level. It is nowhere close to Django in terms of features, but you can find plenty of pluggable libraries to do what you want. In your case, you can find a very nice admin interface here: https://github.com/wearefractal/smog