# Codeigniter Or Node js?

Tags: node.js, codeigniter

I am building a web app for redirection.The web app could have more than 500 concurrent user. 
I had developed so many of projects in codeigniter but as per speed is concern, some people suggest me to switch to node js. Please help me out , would it be good to switch to node js ? What could be advantage of it ?

Comment: You do realize that codeigniter and nodejs are two completely different things... and that you can use codeigniter along with nodejs in your web app; you don't need to switch to any of them you can use both to your advantage

Comment: Is there any way to integrate node js with codeigniter?

Comment: this can  be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062614/how-to-decide-when-to-use-node-js

Answer (score 0):

If you need something easily extensible, which has numbers of libraries built and open sourced that are easily added into your codebase then use CodeIgnitor, it is a great place to start.Pair it with Nginx instead of Apache (and code smart, damnit) and you'll get solid speed.

And if you're building a single page site, you're really great at Javascript, then you can go with Node.

Answer (score 0):

Node js is asynchronous,so it serves request faster,if you are good at JS then node is a good option i think !
look at this link
http://www.toptal.com/nodejs/why-the-hell-would-i-use-node-js

Answer (score 0):

you can try node js also with Sails Js Framework,its a framework some what like MVC Structure as like in Codeigniter framework.you can create your patter structure (controller,model,views)