# What are the advantages of node.js compared to a simple mvc web framework which is run on something like nginx?

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller

I mostly write web apps using Python MVC frameworks which are run on top of nginx.
It's simple and it works. Nginx is pretty fast and Python is a joy to work with.

What exactly can I benefit from switching over to Node? Is there any specific job that Node is best suited for? From what I've seen it's a just cool single-threaded non-blocking process that does the job of both the server and your coding language in one. Javascript is cool too.

Where does Node really shine--if it does that at all?

Would I really be able to handle a lot more requests had I written my web app in node instead of a python mvc + nginx? And will those individual requests be fast as well (without much lag)?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062614/how-to-decide-when-to-use-nodejs?rq=1

Comment: Node shines in real-time applications, and the huge stack of tools/libraries that were developed for that regard. Other than that, python+mvc framework is just as fine (and more than fine, in your case, since you know it well)

Answer (score 1):

nginx / apache:

```
upon getting a request:
    start a process to run it (apache maintains a pool)
    call io (file / database / external web service etc.) synchronously 
                                                   (block wait for a response)
```

node.js / Tornado:

```
upon getting a request:
    use current single thread process to run it (ignoring cluster for simplicity)
    use async programming for io calls
```

given the above, node will perform better in an io intensive applications, but may become irresponsive in a cpu intensive ones.