# Dropdown Functionality in dynamically filled table

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I am trying to fill a table dynamically, depending on the users in my database. For each user I want a dropdown option in order to change his role. I use bootstrap for this dropdown menu, hence I include:

```
  <script src=".\..\javascripts\jquery.js"></script>
  <script src=".\..\plugins\bootstrap-4.4.1-dist\js\bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

I already have the functionality of this dropdown menu in a different ejs file, but there it is only static. It looks like that:

```
<div class="dropdown show">
                        <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink"
                            data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            User
                        </a>

                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" id="Admin" href="#">Admin</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" id="User" href="#">User</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" id="Maintainer" href="#">Maintainer</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

This code is fully functional. Now I am trying to apply the same approach dynamically, but I fail:

```
 //Button for Role
          let roleButtonCell = row.insertCell(i);
          i++;


          //Div for bootstrap for Role Button
          var tempDivRole = document.createElement("div");
          tempDivRole.className = "dropdown show";


          //Role change and display
          var tempButtonRole = document.createElement("a");
          tempButtonRole.setAttribute("role", "button");
          tempButtonRole.className = "btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle";  //ClassName for bootstrap
          tempButtonRole.setAttribute("href", "#");
          tempButtonRole.setAttribute("id", "dropdownMenuLink");
          tempButtonRole.setAttribute("data-toggle", "dropdown");
          tempButtonRole.setAttribute("aria-haspopup", "true");
          tempButtonRole.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
          tempButtonRole.innerHTML = `${user.role}`;



          //DropDown Options for roles
          var tempDropdownRoles = document.createElement("div");
          tempDropdownRoles.className ="dropdown-menu";
          tempDropdownRoles.setAttribute("aria-labelledby", "dropdownMenuLink");

          var tempDropdownItemAdmin = document.createElement("a");
          tempDropdownItemAdmin.className = "dropdown-item";
          tempDropdownItemAdmin.setAttribute("href", "#");
          tempDropdownItemAdmin.innerHTML = `Admin`;
          var tempDropdownItemUser = document.createElement("a");
          tempDropdownItemUser.className = "dropdown-item";
          tempDropdownItemUser.setAttribute("href", "#");
          tempDropdownItemUser.innerHTML = `User`;
          var tempDropdownItemMaintainer = document.createElement("a");
          tempDropdownItemMaintainer.className = "dropdown-item";
          tempDropdownItemMaintainer.setAttribute("href", "#");
          tempDropdownItemMaintainer.innerHTML = `Maintainer`;

          tempDropdownRoles.appendChild(tempDropdownItemAdmin, tempDropdownItemUser, tempDropdownItemMaintainer);

          //Add Button Edit to div and div to cell
          tempDivRole.appendChild(tempButtonRole, tempDropdownRoles);
          roleButtonCell.appendChild(tempDivRole);
```

With this code I get the same situation as in [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined at Object.onLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51006763/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-setattribute-of-undefined-at-object-o).
Hence I removed

```
tempButtonRole.setAttribute("data-toggle", "dropdown");
```

But with or without this line, the dropdown menu does not work: When clicking on the button, no dropdown is displayed.
Instead of the element "a", I tried "select":

```
          var tempButtonRole = document.createElement("select");
```

Now the dropdown appears, but the options are empty and even the innerHTML of tempButtonRole is not displayed, the button is empty. Am I missing any attributes or what am I doing wrong? As mentioned above, the static approach works perfectly fine.

Comment: Is it possible that you publish a quick stackblitz example?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!
I decided to code it a different way, and hence don't have that problem anymore. 
As I am not familiar with stackblitz, it would've taken some time for me to set it up propperly. 
But thanks for you help!